# Redux - How to document the application state?

Tags: javascript, redux

I am working on a React / Redux web application. In the beginning of the project, I had a very good understanding of my application state. But, as the code base grows, I tend to put more and more attributes to the application state through reducers. The problem here is, if a new person joining my project, he may not have a clear knowledge about all the attributes that are already there in the state.

Right now, I am just using a commented out Object in a file called `state.js` to describe all the attributes in the state.

```
/*
    APP_STATE = {
        attribute1 : '',
        attribute2 : '',
        attribute3 : [],
        attribute4 : {
            key: ''
        },
    }
*/
```

The question is: Is there better way to document the structure of my application state so that it is easy to make sense? What approach do you guys use?

Answer (score 3):

A new developer should probably look at things from the origin. In our case, that would be the rootReducer.

The declaration of the rootReducer is typically a combination of multiple separate reducers, each has its own state ("slice"). At this point, I wouldn't document the state of each and every reducer, simply the main structure.

```
// rootReducer.js

export default combineReducers({
   feature1,   // State for feature1
   feature2,   // State for feature2
   ...
})
```

Now the developer could dive into each and every reducer to get familiar with it.
Each reducer has its own module, in which you declare the initialState at the top. A person who looks at the file, could immediately get an idea about the structure of the slice. It's also your opportunity to document it.

```
// feature1Reducer.js

const initialState = {
    attribute1: '',    // description of attribute1
    attribute2: [],    // description of attribute2
    ...
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    ...
};
```

So I guess my main guidelines would be:

1. Don't stress introducing the **entire** thing at once. Separate to multiple files/modules.
2. If you wish to document an object, it might be better to use inline comments rather than comment blocks. In my opinion, it's also easier to maintain. However, this is subjective.